# src attribute is not referring to image in localhost

Tags: jquery, html, json

```
// called onClick
function reqListener(){
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status == 200) {
            var $img_links = jQuery.parseJSON(this.response);
            //serach all the image container of base and change src attr
            $('img.base-image').each(function(index){
                $(this).attr("src", $img_links[0]);
            })
        }
    };
```

Here `$img_links[0]` = `"http://localhost/cocexplore/img/name.jpg"` and the image in my localserver on specified directory but src is not refering to any image and output a small broken image. 
However when i set

```
$(this).attr("src", "http://localhost/cocexplore/img/name.jpg")
```

everything works fine.what is happening here ??

Comment: Do you think you could create a jsfiddle so that we can test the code?

Comment: try this `$("#imag").attr("src",../cocexplore/img/name.jpg );`

Comment: I think you need to use key like $img_links[0].img-url...because $img_links[0] return json object...so you need to use object key to get value

Comment: just console your $img_links to make sure what it is returning

Comment: as per you above code and `json` object i don't see any error. Try alerting `$img_links[0]` before setting the `src` and see if you are getting correct value or not.

Comment: yeah i alerted the $img_links[0] and its value is "http://localhost/cocexplore/img/name.jpg" including double quotes.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the `http://` to that?

Comment: If the image is not loading then there should be a error thrown on the console. If the error is a 404 not found. Then you should add the `http://` part to the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `http://` to the image path. Try adding that to the path. It should work.

Comment: Yes. But in the comment he mentions that the value is returned as "localhost/cocexplore/img/name.jpg".

Comment: Ohh ok, but why would he have fixed the problem in the question? XD

Comment: i don't know why stack its  is ("http://localhost/cocexplore/img/nma.jpg") no small brackets i have alerted the value of $img_links[0] value. and for some reason stackoverflow is excluding http:// i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

`"http://localhost/cocexplore/img/name.jpg"` will never resolve to a real file.
The browser js parser can't just read files off your harddrive. First you need to run a webserver on localhost, then it might work if the server is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1:80.